# How to replace a column with a new data set?

Tags: matlab

I have this randomly generated numbers:

```
Acc_std = 5;
Acc_mu = 15;
Acc_Speed = Acc_std.*randn(15959,1) + Acc_mu;
```

and this column in a dataset:

```
G.Edges(:,5)
```

How can I replace the data in the fifth column with my randomly generated data (`Acc_Speed`)?

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
Error in Team1 (line 48)
G.Edges(:,5) = Acc_Speed
```

Comment: What about `G.Edges(:,5) = Acc_Speed`?

Comment: Make sure that dataset height is 5000 too

Comment: If you use the [`size`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) function, what values does `size(G.Edges)` return?

Comment: @codeaviator it return 15959, i'm updating the random to the same count now

Comment: @Ola Did that change solve the problem? Do you get any errors in the command window?

Comment: no it did not this is the error I'm getting "Error in Team1 (line 48)
  G.Edges(:,5) = Acc_Speed"

Comment: @Ola Can you please upload the **complete** error message to the description of your question? This way we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this example I made based on your code:

I created the following [`table`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html), which I called (`T`):

```
col1 = ones(3, 1);
col2 = 2*ones(3, 1);
col3 = 3*ones(3, 1);
col4 = 4*ones(3, 1);
col5 = 5*ones(3, 1);

T = table(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5);
```

The `table` looks like this:

```
>> T

T = 

    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
    ____    ____    ____    ____    ____

    1       2       3       4       5   
    1       2       3       4       5   
    1       2       3       4       5
```

I use [`size`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) to find the number of rows (`a`) that `T` has, and then generate some random values based on that size (`a`), using the expression and values that you provided:

```
[a, b] = size(T);

Acc_std = 5;
Acc_mu = 15;

Acc_Speed = Acc_std.*randn(a, 1) + Acc_mu;
```

Finally I replace the fifth column (`col5`) of `T` with the values from `Acc_Speed`:

```
T.col5 = Acc_Speed;
```

Now `T` looks like this:

```
>> T

T = 

    col1    col2    col3    col4     col5 
    ____    ____    ____    ____    ______

    1       2       3       4       28.847
    1       2       3       4       8.2506
    1       2       3       4       30.175
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I'm still getting this error "Right hand side of an assignment into a table must be another table or a cell array."

Comment: @Ola Oh, I assumed that you were using a `struct`, but you are actually working with a [`table`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html). Please let me update my answer.

Comment: @Ola Answer updated. Let me know if your problem is solved now, or if you get any errors. Cheers.